# Testing Ionic App on real Android Device with Protractor and Appium

Tags: android, ionic-framework, protractor, appium

I'm trying to test an Ionic 3 App on a real device with Protractor and Appium. I've been using these two articles to help me along the way:

- https://www.joshmorony.com/e2e-end-to-end-testing-in-ionic-2-an-introduction/
- https://crondev.wordpress.com/2018/04/23/e2e-tests-for-ionic-or-any-other-hybrid-app/

Here is my *protractor.conf.js*:

```
/**
 * Protractor Config
 */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'],
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: '',
        appPackage: 'de.softwareforen.mapp.app',
        appActivity: '.MainActivity',
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '5.1.1',
        deviceName: 'Samsung Galaxy J3 (2016)',
        autoAcceptAlerts: 'true',
        autoWebView: true
    }],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    random: false,
    jamineNodeOpts: {
        random: false
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    },
    beforeLaunch: async () => {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e'
        });
    }
}
```

I have a tsconfig.json (like in the first article) and a simple test in a folder "e2e". The app has been deployed on the device (via `ionic cordova run android --device`). I start appium (tried it with and without the chromedriver executable, same result) and protractor. The App gets opened briefly (~3 seconds) on the device but gets closed again while still on the splash screen.

This is the relevant appium output:

```
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\JWA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 420059d197897400 shell am start -W -n de.softwareforen.mapp.app/.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session 33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56 added to master session list
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1525769479329 (10:51:19 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit))
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"","appPackage":"de.softwareforen.mapp.app","appActivity":".MainActivity","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"5.1.1","deviceName":"Samsung Galaxy J3 (2016)","autoAcceptAlerts":"true","autoWebView":true,"count":1},"browserName":"","appPackage":"de.softwareforen.mapp.app","appActivity":".MainActivity","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"5.1.1","deviceName":"420059d197897400","autoAcceptAlerts":"true","autoWebView":true,"count":1,"deviceUDID":"420059d197897400","deviceScreenSize":"720x1280","deviceModel":"SM-J320F","deviceManufacturer":"samsung"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 34095 ms - 857
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56/timeouts
[HTTP] {"script":11000}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted "MJSONWP protocol requires type and ms" and you sent {"script":11000}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56/timeouts 400 4 ms - 106
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56/timeouts
[HTTP] {"type":"script","ms":11000}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: [{"protocol":"MJSONWP","type":"script","ms":11000},"33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] type: script, ms: 11000
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56/timeouts 501 8 ms - 118
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1525769479399 (10:51:19 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit))
[Appium] Removing session 33b83913-d588-44ea-a137-033b60db7f56 from our master session list
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

And this is the protractor output:

```
[10:50:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:50:45] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
[10:51:19] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[10:51:22] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Not implemented yet for script.
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\JWA\Documents\Projekte\MAPP\mapp-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\JWA\Documents\Projekte\MAPP\mapp-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\JWA\Documents\Projekte\MAPP\mapp-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[10:51:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Looks like a timeout problem. Unfortunately I have not been able to solve it so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a typo in the multiCapabilities. It's autoWeb**v**iew not autoWebView.